# (Node 18 y NPM 9) npm ERR! code EACCES, npm ERR! syscall rename

Tags: nodejs

Hace poco desinstalé una versión antigua de Node que venia en mi distribución Ubuntu 20.04 (ZorinOS) e instalé con [nodesource](https://github.com/nodesource/distributions) Node 18.16 con NPM 9.6 con este comando:

```
curl -fsSL https://deb.nodesource.com/setup_lts.x | sudo -E bash - &&\
sudo apt-get install -y nodejs
```

El problema es que al instalar cualquier cosa de forma global, por ejemplo Prettier `npm install -g prettier` me sale el siguiente error. Funciona correctamente si uso `sudo`, pero quiero saber cómo resolverlo.

```
npm ERR! code EACCES
npm ERR! syscall rename
npm ERR! path /usr/local/bin/prettier
npm ERR! dest /usr/local/bin/.prettier-JnqXmybk
npm ERR! errno -13
npm ERR! Error: EACCES: permission denied, rename '/usr/local/bin/prettier' -> '/usr/local/bin/.prettier-JnqXmybk'
npm ERR!  [Error: EACCES: permission denied, rename '/usr/local/bin/prettier' -> '/usr/local/bin/.prettier-JnqXmybk'] {
npm ERR!   errno: -13,
npm ERR!   code: 'EACCES',
npm ERR!   syscall: 'rename',
npm ERR!   path: '/usr/local/bin/prettier',
npm ERR!   dest: '/usr/local/bin/.prettier-JnqXmybk'
npm ERR! }
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! The operation was rejected by your operating system.
npm ERR! It is likely you do not have the permissions to access this file as the current user
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! If you believe this might be a permissions issue, please double-check the
npm ERR! permissions of the file and its containing directories, or try running
npm ERR! the command again as root/Administrator.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in: /home/miusuario/.npm/_logs/2023-04-15T15_24_42_813Z-debug-0.log
```

Comment: El error dice que tu usuario actual no tiene los permisos suficientes, y al usar sudo se confirma eso, prueba reinstalando con nvm o cambiando la ubicación de npm (según la documentación de npm) [Resolving EACCES permissions errors when installing packages globally](https://docs.npmjs.com/resolving-eacces-permissions-errors-when-installing-packages-globally) o darle permiso de escritura a tu usuario para la carpeta /usr/local/bin,